# Bazel select fails inside ctx.file

Tags: bazel

I am trying to specify build conditions based on the os I'm running bazel from, so in my .bzl script I have a rule that makes all the simlinks from external sources and writes a BUILD file (with ctx.file), in which I'm declaring all the imports and libraries and in those I would like to add the select function. However, when I build I get this error message:

```
ERROR: no such package '@maya_repo//': Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/var/tmp/doNotRemove/mdilena_plugins/MayaMathNodes/src/maya.bzl", line 149
                ctx.file("BUILD", _BUILD_STRUC.format(maya_...))
        File "/var/tmp/doNotRemove/mdilena_plugins/MayaMathNodes/src/maya.bzl", line 149, in ctx.file
                _BUILD_STRUC.format(maya_dir = maya_dir)
Invalid character '[' inside replacement field
```

so here's an example of my code and what I'm trying to achieve:

```
_BUILD_STRUC = \
"""
# Windows imports
cc_import(
    name = "Foundation-win",
    interface_library = "{maya_dir}/lib/Foundation.lib",
    shared_library = "{maya_dir}/bin/Foundation.dll",
)

cc_import(
    name = "OpenMaya-win",
    interface_library = "{maya_dir}/lib/OpenMaya.lib",
    shared_library = "{maya_dir}/bin/OpenMaya.dll",
)

# Linux imports
cc_import(
    name = "Foundation-lnx",
    shared_library = "{maya_dir}/bin/Foundation.so",
)

cc_import(
    name = "OpenMaya-lnx",
    shared_library = "{maya_dir}/bin/OpenMaya.so",
)

cc_library(
    name = "Foundation",
    deps = select({
        "@bazel_tools//src/conditions:windows": [":Foundation-win"],
        "//conditions:default": [":Foundation-lnx"],
        }),
    includes = ["{maya_dir}/include"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

cc_library(
    name = "OpenMaya",
    deps = select({
        "@bazel_tools//src/conditions:windows": [":OpenMaya-win"],
        "//conditions:default": [":OpenMaya-lnx"],
        }),
    includes = ["{maya_dir}/include"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
"""

def _impl(ctx):
    maya_src = ctx.os.environ["MAYA_LOCATION"]
    maya_ver = ctx.os.environ["MAYA_VERSION"]
    maya_dir = "maya{}".format(maya_ver)
    ctx.symlink(maya_src, maya_dir)
    ctx.file("BUILD", _BUILD_STRUC.format(maya_dir=maya_dir))


link_maya = repository_rule(
    implementation = _impl,
    local = True,
    environ = ["MAYA_LOCATION"],
)
```

does anyone have any idea why this is happening? I looked at [select](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/functions.html#select) and [configurable attributes](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/configurable-attributes.html#example) docs and seems like that's the way to use it; I wonder if it's me doing something wrong or if there's a bug somewhere.

Thanks for any help!

> EDIT:
>
> looks like Bazel really doesn't like using select inside a ctx.file,
>   I'll leave the question open in case someone will be able to shed some
>   light on it. In the meantime I solved it by making all the `cc_imports`
>   and includes public from the linked repo, while leaving all the
>   `cc_libraries` with `select` to my plugin's BUILD file; from there I'm
>   able to use the condition and everything builds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the error is coming from this line, specifically the call to [`string.format`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/string.html#format).

```
ctx.file("BUILD", _BUILD_STRUC.format(maya_dir=maya_dir))
```

`string.format` searches the template string for curly braces like `{}` or `{key}` and replaces them with positional or keyword arguments.

You're seeing this error because `string.format` is mistaking the dict argument to `select` within the template as something to replace because it starts with a curly brace. Escaping the braces within the template string by doubling them should fix the problem:

```
_BUILD_STRUC = \
"""
...
cc_library(
    name = "Foundation",
    deps = select({{
        "@bazel_tools//src/conditions:windows": [":Foundation-win"],
        "//conditions:default": [":Foundation-lnx"],
        }}),
    includes = ["{maya_dir}/include"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
...
```

FYI, you might find [`repository_ctx.template`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/repository_ctx.html#template) easier to work with. It has slightly different semantics: it replaces strings literally, without looking for special characters like `{`, so escaping is not needed.

Comment: That's perfect, thanks a lot! I completely forgot I was using the format and had to escape dictionaries!